# What's wrong with sending "chr(6)" over a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, wireshark

I'm trying to send ASCII character 6 (acknowledge) over a socket. The socket is connected and sends and receives other information without problem.

The way that I send the acknowledgement is as follows:

```
_socket.Send(data, data.Length, 0);
```

In there, `data` is of the type `byte[]`, the value of `[0]` equals 6 (as it should).

According to socket workbench (a tool, proposed by the customer), nothing is being sent.

According to Wireshard, something is being sent but immediately there's a response, saying that something is wrong:

Wireshark screenshot of the acknowledgement I send:

[image: I send Ack]

Wireshark screenshot of the response I receive:

[image: Response from Ack]

The IP address, ending with 236, is my local PC.
The IP address, ending with 160, is the host where I send the acknowledgement.

According to the colours, used by Wireshard, I suppose something's terribly wrong, but I don't have enough network background knowledge to solve this issue.

Does anybody know what I should do in order to send the acknowledgement successfully?

By the way, this is not a question for Superuser (about usage of an existing computer program), this is about how to develop a program: the Wireshark screenshots are purely explanatory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Getting a RST means the other computer said "WTF are you talking about? I don't know that socket". This usually happens if the program closes the socket or exits or crashes or the computer reboots.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it per se. My own experience of a bug like this (I was seeing a RST, the other end claimed nothing had been received) was buggy AV software filters.

Comment: The socket doesn't care what you send, it is all just arbitrary application data. But maybe the *receiver* may care. Are you SURE you are supposed to send a single byte `0x06` to begin with? What protocol are you implementing?